# Read C file in specific order and find substring

Tags: c

Can someone give me introduction of how to read text file in this order:

```
Line of text here
number1(startposition)
number2(endposition)
Line of text here
number1(startposition)
number2(endposition)
Line of text here
number1(startposition)
number2(endposition)
```

And then find substring of the line with text using number1 as startposition and number2 as endposition and copy the substring in new string.

Comment: They probably can, but the way Stack Overflow works is that you try something and then ask a specific question when you hit a brick wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is an introduction:

- Read one line using `fgets` in a buffer `str`

  - Read 2 lines
  - Convert those 2 lines to numbers using `strtol`
  - Check that the indices make sense (i.e. that they are in the string)
  - Allocate a new string with `length = end - start + 1`
  - Use `memcpy` to copy `end - start` bytes from `str + start`
  - Make sure to add a 0-terminator to your destination string
- Go back to first step

At each point when you do a `fgets` call be prepared for it to fail.

Comment: this case of not include character of the end position.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Indeed the OP should tweak it according to his/her own interpretation of "endposition".